# Statistical Inference: Definition of contrast function

Tags: estimation, inference, estimators

Reading a paper recently regarding results on parameter estimation and I came across the terminology "contrast function" which was a function constructed out of a sample.

If I compare it to [Contrasts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(statistics)) on Wikipedia, it doesn't outright seem to be used in the same sense as in the paper.

Namely, in the wiki article a contrast is a linear combination of variables such that the coefficients sum to $0$; and, in the paper there is no mention of their contrast fitting the criteria of coefficients summing to 0. Rather, in the paper I found it is the form of a function that is a sum of operations carried out on the sample. For instance, difference of the sample points with an auxiliary process of the sample. Or, for instance, a sum of squares of differences between the adjacent sample points. i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^n \lvert X_{t_i} - X_{t_{i-1}} \rvert^2$.

I can reference the paper here if necessary but I don't think it is needed. I would like to know if this usage "contrast function" is standard and if there is a concise definition anyone could direct me to.

**EDIT**: [Simple Estimators for Parametric Markovian Trend of Ergodic Processes Based on Sampled Data](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jjss/35/2/35_2_147/_article/-char/ja/)

Comment: I suspect a reference would be useful because this sounds like an idiosyncratic or highly specialized term.  Your description is so abstract we cannot even tell what the model or application might be, except terms like "auxiliary process" suggest it's not ordinary regression!

Comment: @whuber I have edited the post to include the paper link, it is available in PDF format at the link.

Comment: It's definitely not at all related to a contrast in regression!  I suspect it's related to *minimum contrast estimation,* a generalization of maximum likelihood estimation.

Comment: @whuber Upon searching *minimum contrast estimation* it seems a *contrast function* is also called a *discrepancy function*. Thank you.

Comment: @oliverjones, could you provide your own answer?